# WPF Clickonce in joomla

Tags: .net, wpf, joomla

I have a small wpf application which I want only the registered users of an existing site get access to. Can I publish my wpf application with clickonce in a joomla page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, I have just recently done this.

1. You should publish your WPF app using settings like this:

   - Publishing folder: c:\MyPublishFolder
   - Installation Folder: http://www.yourwebsite.com/ClientBin/ (this can be any folder on our site)
2. Upload all of the files from the c:\MyPublishFolder folder to http://www.yourwebsite.com/ClientBin/
3. Create an article in Joomla and make sure that the editor is the default html editor
4. Add the following link to your article to allow the user to install your app:

<a href="/ClientBin/setup.exe">Install Now</a>

Note that if the user does not have .NET 4.0 or whichever version you have developed your app to use then it will be installed by the installer.

Lastly, so that only registered users can access the download page, edit the menu item that links to your apps install page and set Access to "Registered"

Hope this helps